# LaserScan time_increment

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Following a [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/159711/unknown-tffilter_failure_reasons-in-rviz/) I was wondering what the time_increment in the LaserScan message is for.

The LaserScan.msg says:

```
float32 time_increment   # time between measurements [seconds] - if your scanner
                         # is moving, this will be used in interpolating position
                         # of 3d points
```

However isn't this nothing more than scan_time / ranges.size() ? Seems a bit redundant? In addition, we had this value filled in and it for some reason caused our messages to receive a noticeable delay in rviz. Setting it back to 0 'fixed' this issue.

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163201/laserscan-time_increment/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Caution speculation on my part: I believe the difference to scan_time/ranges.size() is supposed to account for the dead time, when e.g. a 240 deg laser is making a full revolution. The time increment in this case is probably 240/360*scan_time/ranges.size().

As to rviz: This is likely due to the fact that transformations now have to be computed for each individual ray instead of once per scan. However, if algorithms can run "more correct" I would not stay away from this feature due to the visualization, but rather fix rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-05-09**:
As in, make rviz ignore the time_increment value? It is possible the value I had was wrong, but it all just seemed very weird in rviz.